# HTML to PDF - Find out which element is on which page

Tags: .net, wkhtmltopdf

I convert HTML to PDF with wkhtmltopdf by starting a subprocess from .Net. After the processing I need to know the page numbers of some HTML elements. Any idea how to achieve this?

Any alternative (with example code) working on .Net would be fine, too. But it has to respect the [paged media CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least find out the pages of all headings by dumping an outline with `--dump-outline <filename>` and parsing this file.